# AddActorWorldLocation method unintentionally changes the roll value of my object

Tags: unreal-engine4

I'm trying to rotate an object by dragging it through linetrace. Everything work good except that my object starts to rotate as if I were passing It the roll value too.
Is there a way to continuously set the roll value to zero to avoid this unwanted rotation?

Thank you very much.

Here is the blueprint.[image]

Answer (score 0):

Set the actor's rotation with SetActorRotation with Roll 0 and apply GetActorRotation's Pitch and Yaw to it after AddWorldRotation. That's if you want to continue using AddWorldRotation.

I personally would use GetActorRotation + DragWorldRotation then SetActorRotation with Roll 0. This is without using AddWorldRotation.